# The meaning of "Aura"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning and the accurate use of the word "Aura"? 
Does it mean literally " Atmosphere"? 
consider this example: " Heavy snow,, thunders... strong wind. What a lovely aura! "

P.S: I meant by aura not the weather itself but the general atmosphere around me that i feel at that moment.. My feeling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you find in a dictionary?

Comment: @GEdgar - as I have explained in my answer.  The word aura is not simply used for the proscribed dictionary term and the question is valid IMO.

Comment: We try to get questioners to show their research when they ask a question.

Comment: @GEdgar you are simply splitting hairs and I think you know it now as well.  I suspect 99.9% of all questions on this forum do not indicate the sources the checked prior to posting the question and, as I have now said twice, the dictionary route will not lead to the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: I actually looked it up in many dictionaries but still I feel that I'm not convinced 100%. 
My friend told me that I can't use it within the example mentioned in my question.. he says," Aura has this spiritual sense related to energy". 
So, is it really possible to be used in my example?!

Comment: @sam - Hi, the way you used it is fine and perfectly valid (the sentence just needs tweaking slightly) but your friend is being very very prescriptive in how they use the word aura.  Your way is fine.  Unfortunately as per SE mentality this question will never be reopened now regardless of what you do.  A better sentence would be "Heavy snow, thundering, strong wind;  this place has a lovely aura."

Comment: @Venture2099- Got that, thank you very much bro :) :)

Comment: @sam: I think if you add your comment to the question, then it will be released from the "on hold" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aura is a field of subtle, luminous radiation surrounding a person or object like the halo or aureola in religious art.

However, in literary terms the word aura can be used as a descriptive term to draw attention to a particular mood, sense or atmosphere.  In this respect the word aura is used with far more liberal license.

Intended use

> We watched the Pastor deliver his sermon, an aura of energy emanated from the pulpit as he delivered the word of God.

Acceptable use

> The criminal stared at me with murderous intent, his aura radiated malice.

Use with greater license

> The crime scene had an aura of dread which permeated the very air

Comment: Downvoted without a comment?  Not at all childish.  [eyeroll]